# How to find an apt-bsed distro that has the newest packages?

Tags: apt, distributions

I would like to ask what apt-based distros have the most recent packages.  However I know that the question will be closed because for some reason the idea that a distro that has five month old packages having more recent packages then one with year old packages is subjective.

So instead I will have to do it myself. Simple enough just build a scraper, make a list of distros, and find the most recent version of a examplar set of packages and decide for myself.

The question is given a list of URLs of repositories, how can I find the versions of the packages on the site?

Comment: `apt-cache policy package` should give you what you want.

Comment: If that's what you want, use Debian sid, aka unstable.    BTW, "unstable" doesn't mean "crashes all the time", it means "packages are constantly being updated which sometimes results in the system being somewhat broken, requiring a significant amount of knowledge about Linux/Unix in general and Debian in particular to get it back to a working state".   In other words, it has the newest packages that you want, and everything that goes along with them - the good and the bad.

Answer (score 1):

distro watch website has a search function to look for a particular package and select older or newer version or latest version of that package, results show which distros (linux) has the package at the newest version or whichever you select, old, older, etc

so you could search for 'apt' (there's a dropdown menu) and select current version or newest

i am more interested in the video driver (nvidia) so i like to search by that
then  you can decide if you really want an apt distro or whatever, and it will probably be latest, most current, generally; if they bother to include newest nvidia driver.. then most likely the others are as well, packages

another thing is 'rolling release', meaning newest and daily updates probably based on testing versions of apps/packages